# interactive python - keeping console interactive with a GUI mainloop

Tags: python, user-interface, console, nonblocking, interactive

I am wondering how one would create a GUI application, and interact with it from the console that started it.

As an example, I would like to create a GUI in PyQt and work with it from the console. This could be for testing settings without restarting the app, but in larger projects also for calling functions etc.

Here is a simple example using PyQt:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def main():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  w = QtGui.QWidget()
  w.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when this is run with `python -i example.py` the console is blocked as long as the main-loop is executed.

How can I call `w.resize(100,100)` while the GUI is running?

Answer (score 0):

ops, posted wrong answer before

there is a post in Stack about that

[Execute Python code from within PyQt event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893748/execute-python-code-from-within-pyqt-event-loop)

Comment: As far as I see the `QTimer.singleShot` method only allows to excecute predefined functions during runtime. This does not allow for interaction from the console as it is still blocked.
Or am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses the [code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) module to run a console in the command prompt (be sure to run the script from the command line). [Subclassing QThread](https://kushaldas.in/posts/pyqt5-thread-example.html) provides a route by which the console can be run in a separate thread from that of the main GUI and enables some interaction with it. The stub example below should be easy enough to incorporate into a larger packaged PyQt program.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import threading #used only to id the active thread
import code
import sys

class Worker(QThread): #Subclass QThread and re-define run() 
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def raise_sys_exit(self): #more gracefully exit the console
        print('(Deactivated Console)')
        raise SystemExit

    def setup_console(self,global_dict):
        console_exit = {'exit': self.raise_sys_exit}
        self.console = code.InteractiveConsole(locals=dict(global_dict,**console_exit))

    def run(self):
        try:
            print('worker', threading.get_ident())
            self.console.interact()
        except SystemExit:
            self.signal.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.data = [1,2,3,4] #some data we might want to look at

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.b = QPushButton("Interact")
        self.b.clicked.connect(self.b_clicked)
        layout.addWidget(self.b)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.signal.connect(self.finished)

    def finished(self):
        self.b.setEnabled(True)

    def b_clicked(self):
        print('main',threading.get_ident())
        self.worker.setup_console(globals()) #pass the global variables to the worker
        self.worker.start()
        self.b.setEnabled(False) #disable the GUI button until console is exited

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use IPython:

```
ipython --gui=qt4
```

See `ipython --help` or the [online documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/options/terminal.html) for more options (e.g. gtk, tk, etc).

Comment: Could you provide an example on how this is used?
I cannot seem to replicate the example from my post when I run Ipyton with the qt4 gui.
I cannot import QtGui, but I cant use the predefined QtGui either.

Comment: If you get an import error, make sure that PyQt is in your PYTHONPATH. If you are on ubuntu/debian you can install both pyqt and ipython with `apt-get install python-qt4 ipython`. Then you can start the shell with the `--gui=qt4` and begin testing your qt code. When you type `w.show()` the window will instantly show up, without blocking (You don't have to run `app.exec_()` because I guess ipython already does that for you).